# Save shared content to local filesystem

Tags: storage, intents

The [droidentify](http://www.onyxbits.de/droidentify) program allows to save a report of the information it gathers by using the send action intent. Source code extract:

```
    public static void shareReport(Context ctx) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            intent.setType("text/html");
            ...
```

On my device this results in Android presenting four possible recipients, all of which I do not want because I just want to save it to the local file system (/mnt/sdcard or wherever).

Are there any system configuration to enable file system as share target? Or do I have to install some program to do this? I am looking for a free one, with source code available if so.

Comment: Are you developing an app that works in conjunction? Depending on your answer this might be closed as off-topic.

Comment: No, I would like to avoid having to write something myself...

Comment: Alright, flag retracted. It's surprising you went as far as looking into the source code of an app - upvoted for effort.

Comment: have you tried this app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.boxhead.android.sharetofilesystem&hl=en_US&gl=US

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found! There is an excellent program called [Send to SD card](https://github.com/gelin/send-to-sd) which does exactly what I was looking for. Free program with source available, GPLv3.

[image: Screenshot, source: https://bitbucket.org/repo/A9zxob/images/3685259458-send_to.png]

Comment: This was a much more elegant solution than the way I solved it initially: Send via bluetooth to an older phone, switch it into usb mass storage mode, copy from it to my pc and then push to the tablet with adb...